# How to properly pass settings to component in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePhp 2.2.3 and I'm making a component.

Component:

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
class ExampleComponent extends Component {

public $settings = array();

protected $_defaults = array(
    'a1' => null,
    'a2' => 2
);

public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {

    $settings = array_merge($this->_defaults, $settings);
    $this->settings = $settings;

}

public function sum() {
    $sum = $this->settings['a1'] + $this->settings['a2'];
    return $sum;
}

}
```

Controller:

```
class ExampleController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Example');

public function index () {
    $this->set('sum', $this->Example->sum(array('a1' => 2, 'a2' => 3)));
}
}
```

I got back (int) 2 as the result. But I think it should be 5.
What I do wrong?

Comment: why would you pass those and then access them as setting params? you should not mix settings and runtime arguments.

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correct, I need to make some public variables in my component. It will be settings. I can change them using `$this->Example(array('foo' => 'bar'))`.
And in methods of this component I can use this settings to set some 'core' values, but I also need to accept some variables as I do in my controllers actions. And I can pass this variables by using `$this->Example->someMethod($first, $second)`. And this method will use both of this (settings + vars.)?
BTW, do I need to change something in `public function __construct` to be able to pass settings? Or I shouldn't touch it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the default settings at the wrong time. 
`__construct` gets called when you instantiate your component with the following line.

```
public $components = array('Example');
```

So if you want to pass parameters to the component initialization you do it like this:

```
public $components = array('Example'=>array('a1'=>'2', 'a2'=>'3'));
```

If you want to continue to pass the parameters with the following line:

```
$this->set('sum', $this->Example->sum(array('a1' => 2, 'a2' => 3)));
```

Then you will have to adjust your sum() function to:

```
public function sum($new_settings) {

    $sum = $new_settings['a1'] + $new_settings['a2'];
    return $sum;
}
```